# [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)].Unhandled Exception: SqfliteFfiException(error, Invalid argument(s)

Tags: flutter, sqflite

> Unhandled Exception: SqfliteFfiException(error, Invalid argument(s):
> Failed to load dynamic library
> '/data/data/uz.hilolnashr.oltin_silsila/lib/libsqlite3.so': dlopen
> failed: library
> "/data/data/uz.hilolnashr.oltin_silsila/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found})
> DatabaseException(Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library
> '/data/data/uz.hilolnashr.oltin_silsila/lib/libsqlite3.so': dlopen
> failed: library
> "/data/data/uz.hilolnashr.oltin_silsila/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found).

I have just upgraded flutter version. The project was working, but the error appeared. I could not understand what is going on.

I have downgrade versions of some packages but it did not work.

Comment: Hello, the error is related to the SQLite in your project. Kindly. remove SQLite dependency and reinstall  and use `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: I have already done it but it did not help  
  me.https://stackoverflow.com/users/22289437/muhammad-khan-lodhi